# How to replace dplyr functions with others when performing dataframe operations?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm working on my own package in R. All I have left to do is get rid of the build warnings (critpath is my package):

```
Warning: replacing previous import 'dplyr::lag' by 'stats::lag' when loading 'critpath'
Warning: replacing previous import 'dplyr::filter' by 'stats::filter' when loading 'critpath'
```

'dplyr' is definitely to blame because the problem appeared after adding this code:

```
temp_df <- temp_df %>%
    group_by(Step2Col3, Step5Col4) %>%
    mutate(num_dups = n(),
           dup_id = row_number()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(is_duplicated = dup_id > 1)
```

Example dataframe:

```
temp_df <- data.frame(Activity = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M"),
Step2Col3 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9),
Step5Col4 = c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10))
```

Changing the order of calling 'dplyr' and 'stats' in the Imports section of the Description file or using importFrom did not help. The 'conflicted' package didn't help either. So I am unable to get rid of these warnings.

So I have to abandon dplyr and replace its functions with others. Do you know a way to achieve the same effect as the code above, but without using dplyr? The best would probably be 'base', and certainly the safest, but I do not insist.

Comment: You can also just import specific function from packages, no need to import everything

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), IMHO.  The problem is not `dplyr`.  You appear not to be following best practice in developing your package.  As commenters and @giocomai have noted, you should namespace *all* function calls - other than those to functions in `base` - in your package code.  (Or use other methods such as `@importFrom` in roxygen2 comments.  For an excellent reference of best practice in package development, see [R packages 2nd edition](https://r-pkgs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use dplyr in your package, but, as you would do with all functions from other packages, you need to make explicit references to dplyr functions, e.g. `dplyr::mutate` instead of just `mutate`.

If you want to use dplyr's pipe operator (`%>%`), consider running `usethis::use_pipe()` from where you're developing your package, and then you can use it as usual. Also, you don't need to import `stats`.

For more documentation on how to create your package, see in particular: [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/)

Comment: This is another version of my package. The previous ones were no problem. I tried using @importFrom and dplyr::mutate. It didn't do anything. I have to import the stats package because otherwise it pops up a NOTE about the pnorm, qnorm and dnorm functions I'm using. I really spent a lot of time trying to work around those warnings. Without success. The only thing left for me is to give up dplyr since it generates conflicts. Therefore, I am only asking for help in recreating the above code, preferably using the base package.

Comment: if you namespace functions, such as using `stats::qnorm()` instead of `qnorm` every time you use them, you won't get these warnings. Do the same with `dplyr` functions as suggested in my response, and you won't have to load explicitly `dplyr` which is what, I suppose, is triggering those warnings

Comment: I want to be sure I'm doing the right thing. Should I use the reference "::" for both dplyr and stats packages and use importFrom? Because the warnings mention "filter" and "lag" functions, which I don't use.

Comment: yes, you should always use the reference "::" (no need to use if for base functions). But mostly you don't need importFrom, nor use something like "library(dplyr)", which you don't need in packages. Just add dplyr to "Imports: " in your DESCRIPTION, and then use consistently "::". But really, read the linked documentation, it's worth the time